# Easy to install JACK GUI for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, gui, jackd

Does anyone know of an easy to install GUI for JACK on Mac OS X?

Comment: Mr. Man, is there some reason you deleted this post?  the information could be useful to someone else.

Comment: @quack: Sorry, I didn't know what I was doing I guess I found something myself and didn't really think of that.

Comment: well, someone else may have a better answer for you, or if you've found something yourself, please consider posting it as your own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Jack OS X](http://www.jackosx.com/)?  It includes the JackPilot application for controlling the Jack server and managing connections between plugins.

I'm not an OSX user so I can't address how "easy to use" it is.

Comment: Well, kind of, but I'm looking for one with a user interface like qtjackctl.